# I got a problem about convert url to bitmap in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-bitmap

I try to convert url link to Bitmap, and used setImageBitMap but it didn't work.

I think it's because getBitMapUrl function, if i get image from drawable resource, my app still launch

This is my code:

MainActivity:

```
package edu.huflit.comicsapp1;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView rvComics;

    ComicsAdapter comicsAdapter;

    ArrayList<Comics> lstComics;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rvComics = findViewById(R.id.rvComics);

        lstComics = App.initDataForComics();

        comicsAdapter = new ComicsAdapter(lstComics);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this,
                                                                            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
                                                                            false);
        rvComics.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        rvComics.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this,DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        rvComics.setAdapter(comicsAdapter);
    }


}
```

MyAdapter:

```
package edu.huflit.comicsapp1;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ComicsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ComicsAdapter.ComicsVH> {


    ArrayList<Comics> lstComics;

    public ComicsAdapter(ArrayList<Comics> lstComics) {
        this.lstComics = lstComics;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ComicsVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.comics_rows,parent,false);
        return new ComicsVH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ComicsVH holder, int position) {
        Comics comics = lstComics.get(position);
        holder.imgComics.setImageBitmap(Utils.getBitmapFromURL(comics.getImage()));
        holder.titleComics.setText(comics.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return lstComics.size();
    }

    static class ComicsVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView imgComics;
        TextView titleComics;
        public ComicsVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgComics = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgComics);
            titleComics = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleComics);

        }
    }




}
```

My class Utils

```
package edu.huflit.comicsapp1;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Utils {
    public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where i set data:

```
package edu.huflit.comicsapp1;

import android.app.Application;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class App extends Application {
    public static ArrayList<Comics> data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (data == null) {
            data = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }


    public static ArrayList<Comics> initDataForComics(){
        data.add(new Comics("sakamoto", "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/5d/3a/c8/5d3ac8308d52ccdbe98de3778feeb6db.jpg"));
        data.add(new Comics("sakamoto", "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/5d/3a/c8/5d3ac8308d52ccdbe98de3778feeb6db.jpg"));
        data.add(new Comics("sakamoto", "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/5d/3a/c8/5d3ac8308d52ccdbe98de3778feeb6db.jpg"));
        data.add(new Comics("sakamoto", "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/5d/3a/c8/5d3ac8308d52ccdbe98de3778feeb6db.jpg"));
        data.add(new Comics("sakamoto", "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/5d/3a/c8/5d3ac8308d52ccdbe98de3778feeb6db.jpg"));
        data.add(new Comics("sakamoto", "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/5d/3a/c8/5d3ac8308d52ccdbe98de3778feeb6db.jpg"));
        return data;

    };
}
```

Comics.java:

```
package edu.huflit.comicsapp1;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Comics {

   int id;

   String name;
   int category;
   int views;
   int likes;
   String image;
    public Comics(String name, String image) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return views;
    }

    public int getLikes() {
        return likes;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCategory(int category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public void setViews(int views) {
        this.views = views;
    }

    public void setLikes(int likes) {
        this.likes = likes;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

My app cant't

This is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: edu.huflit.comicsapp1, PID: 6614
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1605)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:41)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:178)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:144)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:86)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:176)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.connect(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:90)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
        at edu.huflit.comicsapp1.Utils.getBitmapFromURL(Utils.java:17)
        at edu.huflit.comicsapp1.ComicsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ComicsAdapter.java:41)
        at edu.huflit.comicsapp1.ComicsAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ComicsAdapter.java:22)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:536)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x100
D/goldfish-address-space: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x1efff8000 size 0x8000
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:784)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:22844)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6389)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3470)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2938)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1952)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8171)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

....................